# How to run Coded UI test via MS Agent, from code?

Tags: c#, tfs, automated-tests, mstest, coded-ui-tests

I have a Lab Management environment (2010), with deployed agents and controller, TFS, etc. I have Coded UI tests running successfully on my virtual environments, reporting results to TFS.

What I want to achieve is, to be able to communicate with test agents from my code, essentially acting on behalf of the controller, to run tests. Alternatively, it could be ok to instruct controller itself to schedule a run, but the emphasis is that I want to do it from code.

Do you have any idea how to do that?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can run your tests from the command line using 3 different executables as described here
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182486.aspx

Comment: And just to expand on what is stated in the linked article, TCM.exe is the command-line utility for Microsoft Test Manager.

It is not possible to communicate with test controllers/agents yourself - tests have to be run from either Microsoft Test Manager or Visual Studio (or their command-line counterparts, as mentioned in the article).